# OR in Select Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

```
select * from table1 t1 where t1.column1 = 'someValue' and ((t1.column2 =1) OR  (sysdate < select t1.DateColumn2 + t2.DateColumn2/1440
      from
    table2 t2 where t1.column3 = t2.column3));
```

if t1.column2 =1 evaluates to false, I want to check another condition if time t1.DateColumn2 + t2.DateColumn2 is < sysdate . Oracle is throwing syntax error near or condition. Cant sysdate be used directly like that? Not sure where I am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing. Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: if t1.column2 =1 evaluates to false, I want to check if if time  t1.coulum3 +  t1.coulum2 is < sysdate

Comment: @Ravi, first, give us the sample data with your table structure and the expected output. Then tell us how you want that output to be derived. Asking like this will only waste others time and you will not get the solution that you want.

Comment: You must enclose the subquery that you want to compare with sysdate in parenthesis `sysdate < ( SELECT ...)` and you can't use `ORDER BY` in such subquery, which of course also would have no effect as you select only one (random) row by using `ROWNUM = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am guessing your intention correctly, you want an `exists` clause

```
select * 
  from table1 t1 
 where t1.column1 = 'someValue' 
   and (   (t1.column2 =1) 
        OR exists( select 1
                     from table2 t2
                    where t2.column3 = t1.column3
                      and sysdate < t1.DateColumn2 + t2.DateColumn2/1440 ));
```

Or just join the two tables in the outer query assuming there is at most 1 row in `t2` per `t1` row (if there is exactly 1 row you should do an inner join rather than a left outer join)

```
select t1.*
  from table1 t1
       left outer join table2 t2
         on( t1.column3 = t2.column3 )
 where t1.column2 = 1
    or sysdate < t1.DateColumn2 + t2.DateColumn2/1440;
```